# I don't know where this error occurs in nestjs @module?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, pm2

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { SharedModule } from "./share_modules/share.module";
import { UploadModule } from "./modules/upload/upload.module";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import configuration from "./share_modules/config/configuration";
import { SendMailModule } from "./modules/send-mail/send-mail.module";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { HealthcheckModule } from "./modules/healthcheck/healthcheck.module";
import { KafkaModule } from "./modules/kafka/kafka.module";
import { TestConsumer } from "./modules/kafka/test.consumer";
import { SendMailService } from "./modules/send-mail/send-mail.service";
import {
  Email_teamplate,
  EmailTeamplateSchema,
} from "./modules/send-mail/entities/email-teamplate.entity";
import {
  ThirdParty,
  ThirdPartySchema,
} from "./modules/send-mail/entities/third-party.entity";
import {
  History,
  HistorySchema,
} from "./modules/history/entity/history.entity";
import { HistoryService } from "./modules/history/history.service";

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration],
      envFilePath: [".env"],
      validationOptions: {
        abortEarly: true,
      },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASS}@${process.env.MONGO_HOST}:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/${process.env.MONGO_DB}`,
      {
        retryDelay: 1000,
      }
    ),

    SharedModule,
    UploadModule,
    SendMailModule,
    HealthcheckModule,
    KafkaModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: ThirdParty.name, schema: ThirdPartySchema },
      { name: Email_teamplate.name, schema: EmailTeamplateSchema },
      { name: History.name, schema: HistorySchema },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [TestConsumer, SendMailService, HistoryService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my code, when I use pm2 monit, the communication logs are displayed as "communication > src/app.module.ts(26,2): error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression . │
│ ││ communication > The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1. "  and I don't know where the error is

Fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of our database entities is using a decorator with a wrong amount of arguments. Can you maybe post the content of your entities as well?